# Detecting a class exists and then reordering

Tags: jquery

I want to detect that a div class within a container, that is repeated, exists. I then want to detect if that div class sits before another div class. If it does then I want to move that div to sit after the other div.

```
 <div class="container"> 
   <div class="column1">
   <div class="column2">
 </div>

 <div class="container"> 
   <div class="column1">
   <div class="column2">
 </div>

 <div class="container"> 
   <div class="column2">
   <div class="column1">
 </div>
```

So, in the above example I wish to detect whether column 1 exists and if it sits before or after column 2.

If it sits before column 2 I want to move it to sit after column 2.

I have tried to determine the length/index of the `div`s, but to no avail.
This is my latest attempt. I am a newbie at `jQuery` so forgive me:

```
$('.container').find('.column1').siblings().each(function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    var index2 = $('column2').index();
    if (index > $('column2').index()){
      $(this).css('background','#000');
    } else {
      (this).css('background','#dedede');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will place all the column 1's after the column 2's. You don't need to check if the class exists because if it doesn't then the `insertAfter` method will just do nothing. This is the behaviour of *most* jQuery methods and plugins.

```
// Loop through containers
$('.container').each(function() {
    // Place column1 after column 2
    $(this).find('.column1').insertAfter($(this).find('.column2'));
});
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/h2CYX/

Comment: Nice and simple! How would I go about, instead of detecting the class, detect whether the div has an image in it and place it before the div that has content ie:
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="column1"><img/></div>
   <div class="column2"><p>Text</p></div>
 </div>
Something like this:
$(this).find('.column1 img').parent().insertAfter($(this).find('.column2'));

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.container').find('.column1').each(function(){
    var column1Index = $(this).index();
    var column2Index= $(this).siblings('column2').index();
    if (column1Index > column2Index){
      $(this).css('background','#000');
    } else {
      (this).css('background','#dedede');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately it did not work for me but the above post did.